# How to compare only year from a datetime field in sql server 2008?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table containing a datetime column named:

```
 TranDate
```

So, I have to query through the table to get the data depend on the year only. So,
I am little bit confused about how to do this. My current sql query is:

```
 select * from Angkasa_UnpostedRecords 
 where year(convert(datetime,TranDate,103) = year(convert(datetime,@FromDate,103)
```

But I am getting error in this. Please suggest me how can I do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Error is: "Incorrect syntax near ="

Comment: The syntax error is because you've not closed the brackets properly. You open two, but close only one, on each side of the equality operator

Comment: If `TranDate` is a `datetime` as suggested, then you don't need the `convert` - just `year(TranDate)` is fine

Comment: Thank you so much for getting me to the point...it really helped me to save time..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax error is because you've not closed the brackets properly. You open two, but close only one on each side of the equality operator

Answer (score 6):

I think you could use just the year part

```
select * from Angkasa_UnpostedRecords 
 where year(TranDate) = year(@FromDate)
```

If TranDate and @FromDate are not datetime fields then

```
select * from Angkasa_UnpostedRecords 
 where year(convert(datetime,TranDate,103)) = year(convert(datetime,@FromDate,103))
```

with the opening and closing brackets.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
select * from Angkasa_UnpostedRecords
WHERE DATEDIFF(year, TranDate, @FromDate)=0
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing parenthesis:

```
 select * from Angkasa_UnpostedRecords 
 where year(convert(datetime,TranDate,103)) = year(convert(datetime,@FromDate,103))
```

Notice the extra bracket at the end of each `year(` function